# Movement in A* planning in python

Tags: python, a-star

I am having a hard time getting the star in the code to move from its start position to its end position in python.  I am not looking for they exact answer, but just some help to get me going in the right direction.  I also am wondering how to set the code up to choose one out of five set grids and allow you to choose a start and finish path.  Would I be able to use if statements for the grids if I have it randomly generate a number.  Then use the grid that corresponds with the if statement.

```
import numpy as np
import heapq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

# creating a square grid
grid = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# start point and goal
start = (0, 0)
goal = (10, 15)

# plot map and path
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
ax.imshow(grid, cmap=plt.cm.Dark2)
ax.scatter(start[1], start[0], marker="*", color="yellow", s=200)
ax.scatter(goal[1], goal[0], marker="*", color="red", s=200)
plt.show()

# define Heuristic function

def heuristic(a, b):
    return np.sqrt((b[0] - a[0]) ** 2 + (b[1] - a[1]) ** 2)

# define A-star function

def astar(array, start, goal):
    neighbors = [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)]
    close_set = set()
    came_from = {}
    gscore = {start: 0}
    fscore = {start: heuristic(start, goal)}
    oheap = []

    heapq.heappush(oheap, (fscore[start], start))
    while oheap:
        current = heapq.heappop(oheap)[1]
        if current == goal:
            data = []
            while current in came_from:
                data.append(current)
                current = came_from[current]
            return data

        close_set.add(current)
        for i, j in neighbors:
            neighbor = current[0] + i, current[1] + j
            tentative_g_score = gscore[current] + heuristic(current, neighbor)
            if 0 <= neighbor[0] < array.shape[0]:
                if 0 <= neighbor[1] < array.shape[1]:
                    if array[neighbor[0]][neighbor[1]] == 1:
                        continue
                else:
                    # array bound y walls
                    continue
            else:
                # array bound x walls
                continue
            if neighbor in close_set and tentative_g_score >= gscore.get(neighbor, 0):
                continue
            if tentative_g_score < gscore.get(neighbor, 0) or neighbor not in [i[1] for i in oheap]:
                came_from[neighbor] = current
                gscore[neighbor] = tentative_g_score
                fscore[neighbor] = tentative_g_score + heuristic(neighbor, goal)
                heapq.heappush(oheap, (fscore[neighbor], neighbor))

# creating route
route = astar(grid, start, goal)
# add the start position
route = route + [start]
# reverse the backward sequence
route = route[::-1]
# print route
print(route)

# extract x and y coordinates from route list
x_coords = []
y_coords = []

for i in(range(0,len(route))):
    x = route[i][0]
    y = route[i][1]
    x_coords.append(x)
    y_coords.append(y)
#plot map and path

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
ax.imshow(grid, cmap=plt.cm.Dark2)
ax.scatter(start[1],start[0], marker ="*", color ="yellow", s = 200)
ax.scatter(goal[1],goal[0], marker ="*", color ="red", s = 200)
ax.plot(y_coords,x_coords, color ="black")

plt.show()
```